# Word/Phase Request for Betting On Low Odds

Tags: american-english, phrase-requests

I'm looking for a term/phrase that means: **a bet on low odds**, **someone who bets on low odds**, or **someone who bets against the odds and wins**. Any suggestions would be much appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: Do you mean something like [long shot](https://www.lexico.com/en/definition/long_shot)? *An attempt or guess that has only the slightest chance of succeeding or being accurate.*

Comment: Note that betting on low odds and betting against the odds mean opposite things.

Answer (score -1):

*X **bets against the odds*** means that X makes bets on low odds.

> When you bet for the underdog, it is called betting "against the odds." For example, if odds are 3/1 for the Cowboys this Sunday, then it is three times more likely that they will lose than win. ([Wikihow](https://www.wikihow.com/Read-Odds))

To win by betting against the odds, it helps to (a) know the material well, or (b) hedge your bets by betting on multiple propositions, or both.

Answer (score -1):

**gambling**: "take risky action in the hope of a desired result" (Oxford)

**risk-taker**: "a person who is willing to do things that involve danger or risk in order to achieve a goal" (Merriam-Webster)